# disable auto-completion for all buffers by default in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, buffers, company-mode

Is there a way to keep `auto-completion` enabled as a layer, but have it disabled by default in spacemacs?

For example, I want to have the `auto-completion` layer enabled in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`, but I want auto-completion to start disabled whenever I open up a new buffer.

Currently, whenever I open a buffer, I need to press `SPC t a` (which calls [`spacemacs/toggle-auto-completion`](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/b252d252b0e93249b51400f60a0c69a59aa140a4/layers/%2Bcompletion/auto-completion/funcs.el#L14)) to disable auto-completion.  I'd like this to be the other way around.  I'd like for auto-completion to be *disabled* by default.  I'd like to be able to press `SPC t a` to *enable* auto-completion.

I'm a beginner with emacs/spacemacs, so I'm not sure how I would express this, but one thought would be to call `spacemacs/toggle-auto-completion-off` whenever I open a new buffer.  How would you write this in elisp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `spacemacs/toggle-auto-completion-off` to the `buffer-list-update-hook` by adding

```
(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'spacemacs/toggle-auto-completion-off)
```

to your `.spacemacs`-file (in the `dotspacemacs/user-config`-section). This toggles auto completion off every time the buffer list updates, which happens when you open or close a file or buffer.

Comment: Thanks, this works well.  I ended up going with something like this: `(add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook (lambda () (if (eq 'company auto-completion-front-end) (company-mode -1))))`

Comment: Can this be done only for the REPL loaded using SPC m s b ? I see that when a Haskell program requires user input and when I start typing, auto-completion freezes the entire editor. When I disable auto-completion it works.