# Disabling lsp-mode's autocomplete only for some languages

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

I am on Emacs 27.2 configured with the latest commit of Spacemacs, `develop` branch.

I have both `ocaml` and `lsp` layer enabled. Sadly, I find `lsp-mode`'s auto-completion with the `ocaml-lsp` too slow to use, so I want to disable this feature only for `tuareg-mode`.

So far, I only found global solutions like [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34857/disable-auto-completion-for-all-buffers-by-default-in-spacemacs), but I want a buffer-local, major-mode sensitive behavior. So, building on the previous solution, I have tried:

```lisp
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook 'spacemacs/toggle-auto-completion-off)
```

However, this fails to disable autocompletion on buffers of `tuareg-mode`, maybe because `lsp` mode enables it back.

So, I concluded that I have to tackle `lsp`, not `tuareg`. What settings should I set in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like:

```
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook (lambda ()
                              (setq-local lsp-completion-enable nil)))
```

but make sure that this runs before `lsp` itself.